# How to use a doctrine construct function

Tags: php, constructor, doctrine

Doctrine documentation says you can use

```
public function construct() { ... }
```

as a construct function since __construct can't be overridden.

When I place it in my code and put a echo in it

```
public function construct() { echo "constructing..."; }
```

it isn't called during the construction of the object.

How is it supposed to be called or is there some fancy way of calling a function during (or just after) load time in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because there is no output it doesn't mean that the method is not called. Try a `exit('constructing...');` instead.

By the way: Works fine here with Doctrine 1.1 :-)